# I got data according to this output after running the query

Tags: php

I have this type of data after execution of the below.

[image]

I want those data which are having status `completed` with the only single deliverable.
If same deliverable id having pending and completed both statuses then skip those ids,
In this screenshot case I want `id 3,7;`

Please help.

Comment: Please post code of what you have so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE deliverable IN (SELECT *
                        FROM (SELECT deliverable
                              FROM table_name
                              GROUP BY deliverable
                              HAVING COUNT(deliverable) = 1)
                        AS a) AND status='Completed'
```

Results:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please try this query. It's tested and working fine.